# What is the meaning of "B4αQRUQTπ"?

Tags: kenny-vs.-spenny

In [Episode 1, Season 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgvjCFxf8G4&t=38s) of Kenny vs Spenny, Kenny wears a t-shirt with the text:

> B4αQRUQTπ

*(NOTE: The number 16 is placed directly below the letters (RU))*

I think this is supposed to be a phonetic pun, and I think understand most of it, however I'm stil getting hung up on (αQ).

My current interpretation is:

> Before (?) are you 16 cutiepie

Does anyone have any ideas what (αQ) corresponds to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=alphaQ) the abbreviation alpha Q is sexting code for an expletive.

> It stands for “I’ll f*** you.

Answer (score 3):

This is more than a phonetic pun; it is also a [rebus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rebus) (a representation of words or syllables by pictures of objects or by symbols whose names resemble the intended words or syllables in sound).

It says,

> Before I’ll **** you, are you over sixteen (years old), cutie pie?